# persistent disable of wifi radio when using overlayroot

Tags: wireless

I am using overlayroot on 18.04LTS to create a kiosk, and one of the things I need to do is to be able to permanently enable and disable the wifi radio.

Of course this is simple when not using overlayroot as I can just do:

```
rfkill block wifi
rfkill unblock wifi
```

I cannot use overlay-chroot to do this:

```
overlayroot-chroot rfkill block wifi
overlayroot-chroot rfkill unblock wifi
```

As it errors:

```
rfkill: cannot open /dev/rfkill: No such file or directory
```

And so what I would like to do instead is to programatically update the file or whatever rfkill uses to remember it's settings, but I cannot find this file.

Does anyone know where rfkill stores the devices that it is blocking ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `rfkill` module is likely not loaded. Try doing an `lsmod` and see if you see `cfg802.11` and `rfkill` modules loaded. Check that `rfkill` isn't blacklisted in some `modules.d` blacklist config. Try as root, or `sudo`:

```
grep -r rfkill /etc/modprobe.d/
```

If it's blacklisted, unblacklist it. Make sure `cfg802.11` isn't blacklisted too. That breaks it from loading properly.